# Understand BufferStrategy

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm kind of new to java. I want to make a game. After a lot of research, I can't understand how bufferstrategy works..
I know the basics.. it creates an off-screen image that you can later put into your windows object.. I got this

```
public class Marco extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    BufferStrategy bs; //create an strategy for multi-buffering.

    public Marco() {
       basicFunctions(); //just the clasics setSize,setVisible,etc
       createBufferStrategy(2);//jframe extends windows so i can call this method 
       bs = this.getBufferStrategy();//returns the buffer strategy used by this component
    }

   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g){
      g.drawString("My game",20,40);//some string that I don't know why it does not show
      //guess is 'couse g2 overwrittes all the frame..
      Graphics2D g2=null;//create a child object of Graphics
      try{
         g2 = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();//this new object g2,will get the
         //buffer of this jframe?
         drawWhatEver(g2);//whatever I draw in this method will show in jframe,
         //but why??
      }finally{
         g2.dispose();//clean memory,but how? it cleans the buffer after
         //being copied to the jframe?? when did I copy to the jframe??
      }
      bs.show();//I never put anything on bs, so, why do I need to show its content??
      //I think it's a reference to g2, but when did I do this reference??
   }

   private void drawWhatEver(Graphics2D g2){
       g2.fillRect(20, 50, 20, 20);//now.. this I can show..
   }
  }
```

I don't know.. I've been studying this for a long time now.. and with no luck at all.. I don't know.. maybe it's all there, and it's really clear and simple, and I'm just too stupid to see it..

Thanks for all the help..  :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's how it works:

1. The `JFrame` constructs a `BufferStrategy` when you call `createBufferStrategy(2);`. The `BufferStrategy` knows that it belongs to that specific instance of `JFrame`. You are retrieving it and storing it in the `bs` field.
2. When it comes time to draw your stuff, you are retrieving a `Graphics2D` from `bs`. This `Graphics2D` object is tied to one of the internal buffers owned by `bs`. As you draw, everything goes into that buffer.
3. When you finally call `bs.show()`, `bs` will cause the buffer that you just drew to become the current buffer for the `JFrame`. It knows how to do this because (see point 1) it knows what `JFrame` it is in service to.

That's all that's going on.

By way of comment to your code...you should change your drawing routine a bit. Instead of this:

```
try{
    g2 = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
    drawWhatEver(g2);
} finally {
       g2.dispose();
}
bs.show();
```

you should have a loop like this:

```
do {
    try{
        g2 = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
        drawWhatEver(g2);
    } finally {
           g2.dispose();
    }
    bs.show();
} while (bs.contentsLost());
```

That will safeguard against lost buffer frames, which, according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html#contentsLost%28%29), can happen occasionally.

Comment: Why do we need to dispose() before we have show() the buffer? I assume the graphic object is there only to have graphics functionality, but when it's not needed we "release it's tools and resources" and than show our buffered image?

Comment: @someFolk - It doesn't _have_ to be done in that order; the call to `bs.show()` could be moved inside the `try` block. But there's no particular reason to do so and it's good practice to release system resources as soon as they are not needed.