# What happens when I call "BufferStrategy.show()"?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferstrategy

```
Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
g.dispose();
bs.show();
```

Does calling `bs.show()` actually display the buffered frames?
If so, how? It simply says that it makes *the next* available buffer visible, but how about current buffer? When does it get displayed?

Comment: See here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13590002/understand-bufferstrategy : When you finally call bs.show(), bs will cause the buffer that you just drew to become the current buffer for the JFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html#show()):

> Makes the next available buffer visible by either copying the memory (blitting) or changing the display pointer (flipping).

Simply said it means the `BufferStrategy` becomes the current buffer for the JFrame.